# Does "when" produce object clause in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

The sentence: "Books are gifts when they are acts of love.". The second part after the "when" is the object clause and the sentence is complex, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'object' in this sentence. The main clause is copular, with *books* as subject and *gifts* as a subject complement of *are*. The *when* clause is a temporal adjunct modifying the main clause (or if you belong to a more traditional grammatical sect, modifying *are*).